# FlowDocumentScrollViewer.Selection MouseEnter Event

Tags: wpf, selection, flowdocumentscrollviewer

How I can determine that FlowDocumentScrollViewer.Selection MouseEnter event occured? only in FlowDocumentScrollViewer 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have some idea about that . Explore MouseCapture() static method of Mouse class it will help.Hope this will help.